# What is the difference between PREMIRRORS and SOURCE_MIRROR_URL

Tags: yocto

Yocto defines two variables: `PREMIRRORS` and `SOURCE_MIRROR_URL` for source mirroring.

What is the difference between both variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SOURCE_MIRROR_URL` is used in `own-mirrors.bbclass` to populate `PREMIRRORS`. Thus, using `SOURCE_MIRROR_URL` and `inherit += own-mirrors` is just a shorthand to populate `PREMIRRORS` for all different fetchers (protocols).

See [SOURCE_MIRROR_URL in the Yocto Project Reference Manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-SOURCE_MIRROR_URL)